# Sort columns on multiple lightning datatables separately

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have multiple data tables that I am trying to sort columns on separately. When I click on the column of one table to sort it, the same column on all data tables is being sorted as well.

Update: Using separate data sets on each table, but now I get an error when clicking to sort any column:

[image: this]

None of the columns sort when clicked, but the arrow indicating the sort direction does change.

*datatable.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Tables">
        <p>Table 1</p>
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={dataOne}
            columns={nameColumns}
            sorted-by={sortByDataOne}
            sorted-direction={sortDirectionDataOne}
            onsort={handleSortDataOne}>
        </lightning-datatable> 

       <p>Table 2</p>
       <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={dataTwo}
            columns={nameColumns}
            sorted-by={sortByDataTwo}
            sorted-direction={sortDirectionDataTwo}
            onsort={handleSortDataTwo}>
       </lightning-datatable> 
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*datatable.js*

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const nameColumns = [
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'firstName', sortable: 'true'},
{ label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'lastName', sortable: 'true'},
];
const dataOne = [
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}, 
    { firstName: 'Carl', lastName: 'Smith'}
];

const dataTwo = [
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}, 
    { firstName: 'Carl', lastName: 'Smith'}
];
    
export default class Datatable extends LightningElement {

@track sortByDataOne;
@track sortByDataTwo;
@track sortDirectionDataOne;
@track sortDirectionDataTwo;
@track nameColumns = nameColumns;
@track dataOne = dataOne; 
@track dataTwo = dataTwo; 

handleSortDataOne(event) {
    this.sortByDataOne = event.detail.fieldName;
    this.sortDirectionDataOne = event.detail.sortDirectionDataOne;
    this.sortDataOne(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirectionDataOne);
};

sortDataOne() {
    let fieldName = this.sortByDataOne;
    let sortDirectionDataOne = this.sortDirectionDataOne;
    let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataOne));

    let keyValue = (a) => {
        return a[fieldName];
    };

    let isReverse = sortDirectionDataOne === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

    parseData.sort((x, y) => {
        x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
        y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
        return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
    });

    this.dataOne = parseData;
};

handleSortDataTwo(event) {
    this.sortByDataTwo = event.detail.fieldName;
    this.sortDirectionDataTwo = event.detail.sortDirectionDataTwo;
    this.sortDataTwo(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirectionDataTwo);
};

sortDataTwo() {
    let fieldName = this.sortByDataTwo;
    let sortDirectionDataTwo = this.sortDirectionDataTwo;
    let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataTwo));

    let keyValue = (a) => {
        return a[fieldName];
    };

    let isReverse = sortDirectionDataTwo === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

    parseData.sort((x, y) => {
        x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
        y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
        return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
    });

    this.dataTwo = parseData;
};

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that both your data tables inherit from the same data set, this is normal behavior. If you were assign to your tables data coming from different data sets or variables, then this wouldn't produce itself.

Create 2 data properties with different names, and assign the each property to a different table.

Comment: I created two sets of data with different names but now the data won't sort at all when I click on a column and I get an error. Just updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: because you are sorting your original data, not data1 or data2

Comment: I updated my js class to sort both sets of data, but they only sort one time when clicked. Is there a way I can continuously click to change the sort from, for example, ascending to descending then back to ascending?

Comment: that is a different question altogether. I would suggest you open another post for sorting data in both asc, desc order on click of a button